# How is the data stored in the database?

Tags: plugin-development, database, mysql

I have years of experience with PHP and MySQL, but just starting to develop plugins for WordPress and need some help.

Currently, I am working on a plugin that will add extra functionality to another plugin. I need to read the data stored by the original plugin and manipulate it with my plugin. So far so good, but when I open phpMyAdmin the data stored in the Original plugin table looks like this: `a:2:{i:0;a:11:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:7:"item_id";s:1:"1";s:4:"name";s:9:"section 1";s:5:"limit";s:1:"1";s:5:"order";s:6:"random";s:10:"difficulty";s:4:"easy";s:9:"timestamp";s:19:"2012-05-21 12:29:44";s:9: ...` Can someone tell me how to read this. How is this method for storing data called and are there guides on how to read this data with other plugins.

EDIT: After further studding the code here is what I understand 
- `s:2:"id";` this means: string with 2 character -> "id".
- `s:7:"item_id";` this means: string with 7 character -> "item_id".
- `a:4:{}` this means there will be 4 arguments between the curly brackets. 
The only thing I could not figure out is that is the `i:0;`?

Am I right with the above assumptions?

Thanks,
Radi.

Comment: That's serialized data, and it generally means that you should be modifying it through code, not directly. 

However, yes, the s is a string, the a is an array, and the i stands for "int" which is just a numeric value. i:0 means an integer of zero.

Comment: You are right that I should not modify it directly, but it will help me build my tables better if I understand the data that is going to be stored in them. Vice versa - use the data from the table with a plugin...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a serialized array. PHP is able to read them as if they were regular arrays (or objects, in some cases) by using the `serialize` and `unserialize` functions (WordPress does this for you).

All you need with WordPress to do is use `get_option` (or comparable WordPress function calls to retrieve data) and use the array/object as normal.

I would recommend you avoid editing the data raw in the database, since can really mess things up (I know from experience :) ).

Comment: isn't get_options only for wp_options table? I need to read data from a custom table(e.g. plugin_name_all_results)

Comment: If you're reading from a custom table, you'll need to write your own CRUD api.  Fortunately, there is '$wpdb`, WordPress' database connection and all around great utility, to make your life easier: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb